# Working with system() in R

Tags: r, command, set, system, dos

I'm having some problems using the function System() in R.
I don't really know exactly what kind of commands that I use in ms-dos is possible to 
use in System(). Probably I can use anything but I don't know how.
I have used a few examples on the internet, for example:

To launch a file

```
system("notepad myfile.txt")
```

To launch a shell

```
system(Sys.getenv("COMSPEC"))
```

However, I wanted to use the command SET in order to try to get the user input (I know I could use readline() in R but it won't be useful in my code).
Is it possible to use SET with system()?

I tried to use:

```
system("SET /P uname=Please enter your name:")

system(SET /P uname=Please enter your name:)

system(paste("SET /P uname=Please enter your name:"),wait=FALSE)
```

None of them worked. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `system()` can't find the command to run. Try using `shell()` on Windows to actually be able to run the command: `shell( "SET" )`

Comment: If you install cygwin, then `system` will work.

Comment: shell didn't work, I'll try cygwin.. tks!!!

Comment: Did you try `shell.exec` ?